# trying to install mpdf using composer, but getting version ^6.1?

Tags: php, mpdf

I am trying to install mpdf using composer, but when I try command_prompt "composer require mpdf/mpdf" in my project folder, I get version 6.1 installed instead of 7.x.  Any suggestions?

Windows 11
XAMPP v3.3.0

Any help appreciated!

[command prompt screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZOmv.png)

Answer (score 1):

This can work like this because of php version installed locally. latest version of mpdf or its dependencies can require the specific version of php or its extensions or smth else. If you're not going to run your code locally, you can cpecify target php and exts versions int you composer.json like this:

```json
{
"require": {
        "php": "~7.4.0",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-mbstring": "*"
    }
}
```

You may not get the latest lib version but you will get version that will work on your target system

Comment: Hello Alexey, thank you very much for the feedback.  I checked and I believe I'm running PHP 8.1.6 locally.  Looks like composer thinks I'm running a different version, but not sure why

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that XAMPP didn't have the GD extension. Without GD the highest workable option seems to be Mpdf version 6.1.

To turn GD on change the line `;extension=gd` to `extension=gd` in the `php.ini` file. So basically uncomment the line by removing the `;`.

Then reinstall `Mpdf` in composer.